# Code Crush Android

Tags: java, android

I want to crush the code of my android app so that it's very hard to refactor it.

Which tool do i use to crush the Javacode?

Thanks and best regards, Till

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use something like ProGuard.  It will shrink, optimize, and obfuscate your Java and works with Android.

http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#/manual/examples.html#androidapplication